# SwiftUI: Preview with data in ViewModel

Tags: swift, swiftui

I load my data from a viewModel which is loading data from web. Problem: I want to set some preview sample data to have content in preview window. Currently my preview contains an empty list as I do not provide data.

How can I achieve this?

```
struct MovieListView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()

    var body: some View {
       List{
        ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
                MovieRow(movie: movie)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieListView()
    }
}

class MovieViewModel: ObservableObject{

    private let provider = NetworkManager()

    @Published var movies = [Movie]()

    init() {
       loadNewMovies()
    }

    func loadNewMovies(){
         provider.getNewMovies(page: 1) {[weak self] movies in
                   print("\(movies.count) new movies loaded")
                   self?.movies.removeAll()
            self?.movies.append(contentsOf: movies)}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is possible approach (based on dependency-injection of view model members instead of tight-coupling)

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // create Movie to be previewed inline, say from bundled data
        MovieListView(viewModel: MovieViewModel(provider: nil, movies: [Movie(...)]))
    }
}

class MovieViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private var provider: NetworkManager?

    @Published var movies: [Movie]
    
    // same as before by default, but allows to modify if/when needed explicitly
    init(provider: NetworkManager? = NetworkManager(), movies: [Movie] = []) {
        self.provider = provider
        self.movies = movies

        loadNewMovies()
    }

    func loadNewMovies(){
         provider?.getNewMovies(page: 1) {[weak self] movies in
                print("\(movies.count) new movies loaded")
                self?.movies.removeAll()
                self?.movies.append(contentsOf: movies)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly - ok. I thought maybe there is a special trick of SwiftUI.

Comment: not working giving error while passing viewmodel : "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: Since viewMode is a ObserverObject in the MovieListView, I don't think it can be passed as a parameter from the preview. I am getting the "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" error.

Answer (score 6):

This question was written before `@StateObject` was introduced at WWDC 2020. I believe these days you'd want to use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` because otherwise your view model can be re-initialized numerous times (which would result in multiple network calls in this case).

I wanted to do the exact same thing as OP, but with `@StateObject`. Here's my solution that doesn't rely on any build configurations.

```swift
struct MovieListView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        MovieListViewInternal(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

private struct MovieListViewInternal<ViewModel: MovieViewModelable>: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
       List {
           ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
               MovieRow(movie: movie)
           }
       }
       .onAppear {
           viewModel.fetchMovieRatings()
       }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieListViewInternal(viewModel: PreviewMovieViewModel())
    }
}
```

The View model protocols and implementations:

```swift
protocol MovieViewModelable: ObservableObject {
    var movies: [Movie] { get }
    func fetchMovieRatings()
    // Define vars or funcs for anything else your view accesses in your view model
}


class MovieViewModel: MovieViewModelable {

    @Published var movies = [Movie]()

    init() {
       loadNewMovies()
    }

    private func loadNewMovies() {
        // do the network call
    }

    func fetchMovieRatings() {
        // do the network call
    }
}

class PreviewMovieViewModel: MovieViewModelable {
    @Published var movies = [fakeMovie1, fakeMovie2]
    
    func fetchMovieRankings() {} // do nothing while in a Preview
}
```

This way your external interface to `MovieListView` is exactly the same, but for your previews you can use the internal view definition and override the view model type.

Comment: This is really interesting, I hadn't thought of creating a Preview-ViewModel, but I think it works, especially if both view models are based on the same model.

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly! I did separate the two ViewModels and put the preview ViewModel in the Preview Content folder so it won't go with my build. This is so good though! -Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Further to the answer above, and if you want to keep your shipping codebase clean, I've found that extending the class captured in PreProcessor flags to add a convenience init works.

```
#if DEBUG
extension MovieViewModel{
   convenience init(forPreview: Bool = true) {
      self.init()
      //Hard code your mock data for the preview here
      self.movies = [Movie(...)]
   }
}
#endif
```

Then modify your SwiftUI structs using preprocessor flags as well:

```
struct MovieListView: View {

   #if DEBUG
   let viewModel: MovieViewModel

   init(viewModel: MovieViewModel = MovieViewModel()){
      self.viewModel = viewModel
   }
   #else
    @StateObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()
   #endif

    var body: some View {
       List{
        ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
                MovieRow(movie: movie)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieListView(viewModel: MovieViewModel(forPreview: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick addendum to this, when I implemented it, XCode fixit threw up all sorts of weird errors and fixes, but none were needed.

Comment: This is a fantastic approach! Thank you for sharing it @Kramer! 
I prefer this over the others as like you said, it keeps the codebase clean and doesn't introduce mocks to the app target.

Comment: I wonder if it'd also be good to wrap the `let viewModel: MovieViewModel` within the `DEBUG` with `@ObservedObject`?

Comment: In this context it's not needed as we're replacing a (presumably) asynchronous method to get data with hardcoding to preview layout only.

Comment: Have you been able to make an archive with this? The problem with this solution is, that the preview code is compiled for non-dev builds, but the `...forPreview:` initializer is not available. Thus, archiving fails.

Comment: I've not tried.

Answer (score 3):

So while @Kramer's solution works, I hit a challenge with it in the sense that when I would debug the app on my device it would load the preview data and not other "development" data that I would be wanting to be using.

So I extended the solution a little by creating a new build configuration called "Preview" and then wrapped all the 'preview' related data into that build configuration.

That gives me the option then to preview dummy data in the Xcode preview, while still allowing me then to build and debug a development build with development data on my devices/simulators.

So my solution now looks like this..

```
class MovieViewModel: ObservableObject {
   init() {
      #if PREVIEW
         //Hard code your mock data for the preview here
         self.movies = [Movie(...)]
      #else
        // normal init stuff here
      #endif
   }
}
```

```
struct MovieListView: View {

   #if PREVIEW
   let viewModel: MovieViewModel

   init(viewModel: MovieViewModel = MovieViewModel()){
      self.viewModel = viewModel
   }
   #else
    @StateObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()
   #endif

    var body: some View {
       List{
        ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
                MovieRow(movie: movie)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieListView(viewModel: MovieViewModel())
    }
}
```

Might not be the best crack at this, but gave me the flexibility to manage my Preview dummy data separate to my development/Debug data and has so far proven to work well for my use cases so far. :)

Comment: How did you create this build configuration? :)

Comment: @Simon How did you created that build configuration?
I tried to create one by:
1) project > info > configuration > duplicate Debug
2) project > build settings > swift compiler - custom flags > active compilation conditions > add "Any architecture | any sdk" > DEBUG PREVIEW
3) edit scheme > run > build configuration > preview

However my preview fails to load.

Comment: @ThinkDeep ah apologies! I see I was a bit vague on the steps here.
Basically what I see that I did was make use of the "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" Build Setting and added an 'Active Compilation Condition` for a `Preview` scheme I created called `PREVIEW`. Then in your swift code you can access/reference that flag.

I see this article details it

https://medium.com/@ytyubox/xcode-preprocessing-with-custom-flags-in-swift-4bfde6e7a608

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been voted higher...it works, it's simple, and it keeps the preview-only stuff completely out of your shipping code. Finally, a solution–thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this as well and came up with the following simple solution.

```
//View
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    init(forPreview: Bool = false) {
        guard forPreview else { return }
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
        viewModel.title = "Preview" // Call internal func to load sample data
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.title)
    }
}

//View Model
extension MyView {
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var title: String = "Standard"
    }
}

//Previews
struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView(forPreview: true)
    }
}
```

This initialization of `@StateObject` is Apple approved.

[image]

Comment: Was trying this approach for small project, this one cleaner

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 15, you will be able to inject data very easily; you can paste this code into your SwiftUI file and play around.

Note: original code incorrectly instantiate the ViewModel onto `@ObservedObject` as pointed out by `lorem ipsum`, corrections are made:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Defining view
struct SampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(viewModel.sampleText)")
    }
}

// Defining view model
extension SampleView {
    @MainActor class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
        @Published var sampleText = ""
    }
}

// Preview running in Xcode 15, tested on iOS 16.4 target
#Preview { // Swift 5.9 preview macro
    var viewModel = SampleView.ViewModel()
    viewModel.sampleText = "A sample text injection" // viewModel data injection
    return SampleView(viewModel: viewModel) // making view use the data in view model
}
```

Comment: `StateObject` is the only safe way to initialize an `ObservableObject` in a `View`.

Comment: This is a very broad statement, and it is not always true. ```@StateObject``` should be the single source of truth, and ```@ObservableObject```gets the source of truth from somewhere else, such as a parent view passing viewModel into a child view. Moreover, this code still works if you change the view to using ```@StateObject```, making it a great alternative to other answers.

Comment: Like I said "initialize in a View", if it gets it from somewhere else it isn't initializing. `@StateObject` is for initializing and `@ObservedObject` is for passing around. It can't hold on to the object, it will get initialized multiple times.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app from Apple

Comment: Thank you for the info ```Iorem ipsum```. I read the link you provided, and I think the Apple documentation does not say ```@ObservableObject``` should be avoided in view at all costs, evidenced by the following quote: *"You can use the object locally, or pass the state object into another view’s observed object property, as shown in the above example"*. Do you feel my ```SampleView``` is the equivalent of ```LibraryView``` in Apple's example instead of ```BookView```?

Comment: `LibraryView` it is initializing `ViewModel`. I didn't say avoid at all costs I said `@StateObject` is for initializing and `@ObservedObject` is for passing around.

Comment: I agree that ```@StateObject``` is for initializing and ```@ObservedObject``` is for passing around. I guess I am more confused about why the way I represent **SampleView** leads you to consider **SampleView** should initialize **ViewModel**, as I think the **SampleView** can be considered the **BookView** in Apple's example.

Comment: ViewModel() == initializing you have done that not me

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean now. Appreciate your patience when I do not understand that you are pointing out I incorrectly instantiated the ViewModel to ```@ObservedObject```, must be very frustrating. Modified the code to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If the Views are functions of state with simple data type or its derivations, then it will be easy to preview them.

The View you have

```
struct MovieListView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()

    var body: some View {
       List{
        ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
                MovieRow(movie: movie)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here viewModel is some complex object with dependencies. So instead of trying to inject this MovieViewModel to your component. Just create another child component and just send the Movies list as param. Like,

```
struct MovieListView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()

    var body: some View {
       MovieListChild(viewModel.movies)
    }
}


struct MovieListChild: View {
    let movies: Movies

    var body: some View {
       List{
        ForEach(movies) { movie in
                MovieRow(movie: movie)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}

// Then just preview this MovieListChild instead of previewing MovieListView, and send your fake list of Movies as param.


struct MovieListChild_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieListChild([Movie("Rambo"), Movie("Fast and Furious")])
    }
}
```

This requires wrapping the View in another View for the sake of previewing, but it's cleaner than creating a protocol for ViewModel or making changes to init of the ViewModel. It is a tradeoff.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app